# How can I shard request using Aeron Cluster

Tags: sharding, aeron

I'd like to understand the capabilities of Aeron Clusters with respect to sharing requests across different back-end cluster application instances.  I am thinking of something similar to partitions in Kafka where distinct back-end consumer processes the workload in independent processes.  There should be a partition key which defines how to find the partition, or it could be a consumer provided hash, etc.

I read this article but it was not much help https://aeroncookbook.com/aeron-cluster/on-sharding/

So far I have only been reading the documentation and the API documents.
I also read the aeoroncookbook site: https://aeroncookbook.com/aeron-cluster/on-sharding/

Could someone provide an example of this if it is possible?  The cookbook does not really do much good here because it imposes a similar problem but with dependencies between the shards.

Answer (score 1):

Aeron Cluster does not directly support sharding.  Its primary goal is redundant copies of the same data across multiple nodes.  Sharding would need to be something that layered on via your own application logic.  An approach would be to run multiple clusters and utilize a key to partition data across the clusters, then within your client application run multiple cluster clients (one for each cluster) and select the approach client based on the data that you are interacting with.

Comment: Thanks much- this would be a great item for the documentation.